# Call another action from one action of the same controller

Tags: php, yii, controller

I am new to YII. How to call an action from another action of the same controller.
Suppose I am in action A. I need to call action B with two parameters. My controller name is Master Controller. How will I perform this. Please say me a solution. Thanks in advance.

My controller:

```
class NimsoftController extends Controller
{
    public function actionStore_action($action,$data_id)
    {
          $model= new NimsoftUserLoginAction;
          $model->user_id=Yii::app()->user->id;
          $model->action=$action;//"Deleted";
          $model->affected_data_id=$data_id;//"22";
          $model->save();
    }

    public function actionSearch($id)
    {
        $cust_id = $id;
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->condition = "host_customer_id = '$cust_id'";
        $details = NimsoftHost::model()->find($criteria);

        $criteria2 = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria2->condition = "cust_id= '$details->host_customer_id'";
        $name = MasterCustomers::model()->find($criteria2);

        $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('NimsoftHost', array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>40)
        ));
        $model = new NimsoftHost();
        $this->actionStore_action(array('action'=>'search', 'data_id'=>$cust_id));
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'details' => $details,
            'name' => $name->cust_name,
            'model' => $model
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply call the function directly, or,

```
$this->actionMyCustomAction(); exit;
```

you can perform a redirect to the action:

```
$this->redirect('anotherControllerName/myCustomAction');
```

or this if you are in the same controller:

```
$this->redirect('myCustomAction');
```

---

**UPDATE**:

You are passing the variables wrongly:

```
$this->actionStore_action(array('action'=>'search', 'data_id'=>$cust_id));
```

It should be two separate variables:

```
$this->actionStore_action('search', $cust_id);
```

**This has NOTHING to do with Yii. It's only basic function calling.**

Comment: I used:
$this->actionStore_action(array('action'=>'search','data_id'=>$cust_id));

it gives me,
Missing argument 2 for NimsoftController::actionStore_action(), called in D:\xampp\htdocs\itsm_admin\protected\controllers\NimsoftController.php on line 847 and defined 
Error

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->forward('site/contact');
```

In case of forward your URL will not be change and you cannot send extra parameter in this.

If you want to send extra parameter then use redirect.

```
   $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('site/contact', array('id' => '22')));
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: If I use redirect, It stays into the same controller action. I must perform some more manipulation after completing that action

Comment: Plz check updated answer. use create url. After this you need not to perform any other manipulation.

Comment: that is what gaurav. It stays in the Store_action. I must render my index.php after executing this action. Please look into my code

Comment: you want to call same function of controller. In this case there is no  need to add action before function name. this is simple you can call function of same controller using $this->functionName().

Comment: It's little bit confusing you wrote you are in action A and want to call action B. So I gave solution to call action B from action A.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way also:-

Now you want to call action Name1 inside action Name2.

```
public function actionName1($param1,$param2) {

    //your code...

}

public function actionName2() {

    $this->redirect(array('name1','param1'=>'param1','param2'=>'param2'));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of forward your URL will not be change and you cannot send extra parameter in this.

```
$this->redirect('contact');
```